# how to count the length of a substring from one character to other in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to update length of a substring from a string in sql (Oracle 11g)

from this>> `#L1313.0000002.CGNMC`  to this>> `#L1313.0000000002.CGNMC`

I want to count the length of string between the dots(.) and if it is less than 10 then i want to append as many as zeros to make it of 10

Counting the entire length of the String is not helping as the changes are only to be done in the substring.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
select lpad(substr('#L1313.0000002.CGNMC',
                   instr('#L1313.0000002.CGNMC','.') + 1,
                   instr('#L1313.0000002.CGNMC','.',1,2) -
                     instr('#L1313.0000002.CGNMC','.') - 1),
            10, '0') from dual;
```

`lpad('x',10,'0')` - adds char '0' to the string 'x' up to size 10

`substr(string, start, length)` - returns substring

`instr(string,substring[,start[,occurence]])` - returns position of a substring in string. start is starting point for searching, occurence means search for n'th occurence of string.

See oracle doc https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions.htm#SQLRF006

Comment: Your solution is incomplete. OP wants to do it only when the length of the substr between the dots is less than 10.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Probably yes. The question does not specify, if there are data with more than 10 characters between dots. In that case I would add <code>CASE...WHEN ... ELSE</code> similar to your example

Comment: Yes, that's was I was trying to point out. When the string already has more than 10 characters, you will force it to 10. Anyway, hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with combination of:

- **SUBSTR**
- **INSTR**
- **CASE**
- **DECODE**

**How does the below query work:**

SUBSTR will give me the part of the strings, INSTR will give me the location of the dot. CASE is to check the condition for the length of the substring between the dots, and finally DECODE will let me do the final job to append the required zeros.

**Test case**

I am considering all possible scenarios.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT '#L1313.0000002.CGNMC' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  3    SELECT '#L1313.002.CGNMC' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  4    SELECT '#L1313.00123.CGNMC' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  5    SELECT '#L1313.12345.CGNMC' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  6    SELECT '#L1313.12345678910.CGNMC' str FROM dual
  7    )
  8  SELECT str,
  9    CASE
 10      WHEN instr(str, '.', 1, 2)         - instr(str, '.', 1, 1) -1 < 10
 11      THEN DECODE((instr(str, '.', 1, 2) - instr(str, '.', 1, 1) -1),
 12                                                   9, (SUBSTR(str, 1, instr(str, '.', 1, 1))
 13        ||'0'
 14        ||SUBSTR(str, instr(str, '.', 1, 1) + 1)), 8, (SUBSTR(str, 1, instr(str, '.', 1, 1))
 15        ||'00'
 16        ||SUBSTR(str, instr(str, '.', 1, 1) + 1)), 7, (SUBSTR(str, 1, instr(str, '.', 1, 1))
 17        ||'000'
 18        ||SUBSTR(str, instr(str, '.', 1, 1) + 1)), 6, (SUBSTR(str, 1, instr(str, '.', 1, 1))
 19        ||'0000'
 20        ||SUBSTR(str, instr(str, '.', 1, 1) + 1)), 5, (SUBSTR(str, 1, instr(str, '.', 1, 1))
 21        ||'00000'
 22        ||SUBSTR(str, instr(str, '.', 1, 1) + 1)), 4, (SUBSTR(str, 1, instr(str, '.', 1, 1))
 23        ||'000000'
 24        ||SUBSTR(str, instr(str, '.', 1, 1) + 1)), 3, (SUBSTR(str, 1, instr(str, '.', 1, 1))
 25        ||'0000000'
 26        ||SUBSTR(str, instr(str, '.', 1, 1) + 1)), 2, (SUBSTR(str, 1, instr(str, '.', 1, 1))
 27        ||'00000000'
 28        ||SUBSTR(str, instr(str, '.', 1, 1) + 1)), 1, (SUBSTR(str, 1, instr(str, '.', 1, 1))
 29        ||'000000000'
 30        ||SUBSTR(str, instr(str, '.', 1, 1) + 1)) )
 31      ELSE
 32        str
 33    END new_str
 34  FROM DATA;

STR                      NEW_STR
------------------------ ---------------------------------------------
#L1313.0000002.CGNMC     #L1313.0000000002.CGNMC
#L1313.002.CGNMC         #L1313.0000000002.CGNMC
#L1313.00123.CGNMC       #L1313.0000000123.CGNMC
#L1313.12345.CGNMC       #L1313.0000012345.CGNMC
#L1313.12345678910.CGNMC #L1313.12345678910.CGNMC

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had used update,instr and substr

```
update table set column_name= case
when (instr(column_name,'.',1,2)-instr(column_name,'.',1,1)-1)<10 then substr(column_name,0,instr(column_name,'.',1,1))||lpad(substr(column_name,instr(column_name,'.',1,1)+1,instr(column_name,'.',1,2)-instr(column_name,'.',1,1)-1),10,'0')||substr(column_name,instr(column_name,'.',1,2))
end
;
```

check the following query for demo

```
select substr('L1313.0000002.CGNMC',0,instr('L1313.0000002.CGNMC','.',1,1))||lpad(substr('L1313.0000002.CGNMC',instr('L1313.0000002.CGNMC','.',1,1)+1,instr('L1313.0000002.CGNMC','.',1,2)-instr('L1313.0000002.CGNMC','.',1,1)-1),10,'0')||substr('L1313.0000002.CGNMC',instr('L1313.0000002.CGNMC','.',1,2)) from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a function which will do the work, please check if it works for you.

```
SQL>    create or replace function paddingstr1( inval varchar2) return varchar2 is
  2     lval varchar2(100):=inval;
  3     final_str varchar2(100);
  4     str3 varchar2(100);
  5     str2 varchar2(100);
  6     str1 varchar2(100);
  7     lpad_str varchar2(100);
  8     pos1 int;
  9     pos2 int;
 10     getval int;
 11     begin
 12     select instr(lval,'.') into pos1 from dual;
 13     select instr(lval,'.',1,2) into pos2 from dual;
 14     getval:=pos2-pos1-1;
 15     pos1:=pos1+1;
 16     select substr(lval,pos1,getval) into lpad_str from dual;
 17     select lpad(lpad_str,10,'0')  into str2 from dual;
 18     select substr(lval,1,pos1-1) into str1 from dual;
 19     select substr(lval,pos2) into str3 from dual;
 20     final_str:= concat (str1,concat (str2,str3));
 21     return final_str;
 22     end;
 23  /

Function created.

SQL> select paddingstr1('#L1313.0000002.CGNMC') from dual;

PADDINGSTR1('#L1313.0000002.CGNMC')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#L1313.0000000002.CGNMC

SQL> select paddingstr1('#LAD313.002.ERGH') from dual;

PADDINGSTR1('#LAD313.002.ERGH')
------------------------------------------------------------
#LAD313.0000000002.ERGH
```